# How to use an init container to check if MySQL is ready for connections?

Tags: kubernetes, sh

Friends, I am learning here and trying to implement an init container which checks if MySQL is ready for connections. I have a pod running MySQL and another pod with an app which will connect to the MysSQL pod when its ready.

No success so far. The error I am getting is the following: `sh: mysql: not found`. This is how I am trying:

```
initContainers:
- name: {{ .Values.initContainers.name }}
  image: {{ .Values.initContainers.image }}
  command:
  - "sh"
  - "-c"
  - "until mysql --host=mysql.default.svc.cluster.local --user={MYSQL_USER} 
  --password={MYSQL_PASSWORD} --execute=\"SELECT 1;\"; do echo waiting for mysql; sleep 2; done;"
```

Any idea how I could make this work?

Comment: which image are you using in init container?

Answer (score 5):

Please try using this.

initContainers:

```
    - name: init-cont

      image: busybox:1.31

      command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo -e "Checking for the availability of MySQL Server deployment"; while ! nc -z mysql 3306; do sleep 1; printf "-"; done; echo -e "  >> MySQL DB Server has started";']
```

Comment: thank you. your solution is working very well.

Answer (score 2):

Do absolutely nothing; even delete the `initContainers:` you have now.

Let's say your application starts up before the database is ready.  It tries to connect, fails, and exits.  Kubernetes notices this, so it will try to start the application again; if it fails repeatedly, it will start waiting progressively longer between retries (you will see CrashLoopBackOff state).  Eventually the cluster will have waited long enough that the database is ready, and the next retry will be successful.

Note that this is probably the same thing that will happen if the database restarts after the application is already running; "at startup time" doesn't need to be a special case.

Comment: I don't agree, init container can be very useful for faster debugging as it will fail early and with easy to digest error message. not all application start by checking the state of the db.  The command posted by OP is not a good on to check that though

Comment: This answer does not address the question.

Comment: It depends the use case, if this is a job that setup the DB ....

Answer (score 2):

Your initContainer is missing the `mysql` client binary.

There are a few ways to solve this:

1. Use an official mysql docker image, and use what you have as the command.
2. Create your own docker image from a base image (e.g. Alpine), install mysql-client, and then modify your initContainer to work with Alpine.

Assuming Alpine is your base image you would have a dockerfile like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.14
RUN apk add mysql-client
```

Then your initContainer command would be:

```
command:
  - "/bin/ash"
  - "-c"
  - "until mysql --host=mysql.default.svc.cluster.local --user={MYSQL_USER} 
  --password={MYSQL_PASSWORD} --execute=\"SELECT 1;\"; do echo waiting for mysql; sleep 2; done;"
```

My recommendation, use the official mysql docker image

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have installed mysql in your init container . it's seems like you haven't install mysql in your init container. as you are trying to connect as a client from another container rather than mysql. you also need mysql installed in your init container. you can use a mysql image or just install mysql in your container when you are building your docker file of init container.

Comment: MySQL is in another pod. I want the init container to check if the database in the other pod is ready because the container which will be created in the same pod as this init container needs it. That was the idea.

Comment: can you share your init container's docker file?